# allocate more memory to a process - Windows 7

Tags: performance, memory

I am running a simulation and it takes long time to be finished. My RAM is 64 Gb. But even when I set the priority to high or even real time the process has max. 31 Gb memory allocated. How can I increase it? Thanks.

Comment: Windows does not limit the amount of memory available. The app did not request more. Reconfigure it.